# Will this home-made airlock work?

Tags: airlock

This is a makedo airlock; I couldn't make it shorter as the loop bends itself and air couldn't pass through.

https://imgur.com/gallery/TOA6i7f

Answer (score 5):

It will probably be OK. The smaller the bore of the tube, the greater the tendency will be for any bubbles to push the liquid right out. You could just make a blow-off instead by submerging the venting end of the tube in a vessel full of water.

Comment: I second the water vessel idea. That prevents insects like fruit flies from entering.

Comment: I agree. Just 1/2 fill the bottle and submerge the tube. Using a loop can easily blow out and go dry.